# Работа с Unicode в С++

Tags: c++, unicode

День добрый!

Хочу написать на С++ словарь с использованием Unicode символов, базу слов использовать в .txt формате. К файлу со словами к строкам обращаться через потоки,  точнее хочу использовать "fopen". Результат выводить в Edit.

Так вот, как обращаться к строкам через потоки?

Answer (score 2):

Чтение строки - `fgets()`. Если хотите работать с широкими символами, то `fgetws()`. Можно сразу анализировать строку с помощью `fscanf()` (для `wchar_t` - `fwscanf()`).